# No dropdown option of IntelliJ in IDE version of Remote Development using SSH in JetBrains Gateway

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, remote-server, intellij-14, jetbrains-gateway

I am trying to connect to a remote server using **JetBrains Gateway**, so that I can use **IntelliJ IDE** for code changing purposes.

Both IntelliJ and JetBrains Gateway are *-newly installed-* on my device and I've rebooted my PC after installation as well.

I entered the hostname, password and it says that I'm **"Successfully Connected"**.

[image]

But in the **IDE version dropdown**, nothing shows up even though I have IntelliJ installed on the system.

I do see the `Other options...` link. But the following options seem like they are to be used if no IDE is installed :

[image]

##### My Question is

How to get IntelliJ IDE (which is already installed) in the dropdown of JetBrains Gateway

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a script to turn the server on

"The main script to run a remote IDE is remote-dev-server.sh, located in the bin subdirectory of your unpacked IDE"

From the Jetbrains instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/remote-development-a.html#use_idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can download a Linux version IDE on your local PC from Jetbrains and use the 'Upload installer file' option. Then the Gateway will upload and install this file to the remote server.

PS. The downloaded IDE file would be like 'ideaIU-2023.2.1.tar.gz'